# A section is overlapping another in Google Sheets code

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am running a 2 variable system in google sheets using if statements. The problem is 1 of the 4 possible answers will show up as blank. How it works is dependent on if an x is there or not and plus another item or not. EquipedI9 is the added amount, E17 is the x slot which adds R15. When e17 = "" and I9 = "" it shows up as blank even though there is a if statement that should not allow this to happen. The whole point of the code is to figure out the number then put the right amount of plusses or minus symbols in front of it

```
=if(E17="",if(Equipped!I9=0,N3,),if(E17="",if(Equipped!I9=0,"","+" & N3+Equipped!I9),if(E17="",if(Equipped!I9="",N3,""),if(E17="x",if(Equipped!I9="","+",),) & if(Equipped!I9="","","+") & if(E17="x","+" & IF(E17="",IF(Equipped!I9="","+",),) & N3+R15,if(Equipped!I9="",if(E17="",,"+"),) & N3) + Equipped!I9)))
```

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with exammple of desired result

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gTG5FJfGCAcGY2XqpdGxyEBMuReAngY_yrrqyhAvXyg/edit?usp=sharing                                                                                ,look at Stats!H17 it is blank I need it to have it equal N3 if Equipped!I9 = blank and if E17 = blank

Answer (score 0):

> Stats!H17 it is blank I need it to have it equal N3 if Equipped!I9 = blank and if E17 = blank

delete **Equipped!I9** and try:

```
=IF(AND(E17="", Equipped!I9=""), N3, )
```

[image: 0]